# Is the first entry in sys.path supposed to represent the current working directory?

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

I had always assumed that the first entry in `sys.path` by default was the current working directory.  But as it turns out, on my system the first entry is the path on which the script resides.  So if I'm executing a script that's in `/usr/bin` from `/some/directory`, the first entry in `sys.path` is `/usr/bin`.  Is something misconfigured on my system, or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design:

> As initialized upon program startup,
>   the first item of this list, `path[0]`,
>   is the directory containing the script
>   that was used to invoke the Python
>   interpreter.

*source: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path*

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current directory with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: I understand that.  I was just somewhat dumbfounded when celery wasn't able to find the celeryconfig file in the current directory.  :-)